# Change text location in CSS

Tags: css, compatibility

I'm currently using following login form where I want to change the design a bit:

http://html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-login-form.html

I want to place ' Login ' into the middle of the box, instead the left:

I've also found out that you can change the textsize, font etc. in fg_membersite.css (line 17). What's interesting is that in Chrome it IS displayed in the middle, only in Firefox it's shown on the left. Since I'm a new CSS worker I wanted to ask if anybody could help me fixing this incompatiblity problems here.

Since it also contains lots of Javascript based stuff I wasn't sure if I posting source codes here would be sensible, because I'd have to post the whole source anyway then.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Much prettier now. Thanks:

http://rapidhdd.com/images/4013242013-10-06_1842.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for the center text part:

```
<form id='login' action='login.php' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset >
<legend align="center">Login</legend>
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

<label for='username' >UserName*:</label>
<input type='text' name='username' id='username'  maxlength="50" />

<label for='password' >Password*:</label>
<input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />

<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />

</fieldset>
</form>
```

I guess you've changed the HTML code but note the: `<legend align="center">Login</legend>`

**align="center"**

http://jsfiddle.net/4szBC/

---

EDIT:

Since it seems like align is deprecated you, can do this using by using css.

```
legend {
    text-align: center;
}
```

If you want the css right in HTML, add it in a `<script>` tag and place it in `<head>`. Like this:

```
<script type="text/css">
    legend {
        text-align: center;
    }
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4szBC/1/

Comment: `align` attribute is deprecated and you shouldn't propose that as a solution

Comment: Didn't know that. My apologies! Changed my answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer first! Really appreciate it, I have searched for solutions all day... The problem just is - it's Firefox fault. I have tried adding it as a script and adding it to the CSS file, under Chrome it's displayed correct, just Firefox makes problems. If you want I can upload it on a public FTP server

Comment: Yep, aligning it with <legend> worked, and it also still works under IE & Chrome. Thanks!

Comment: Np! Since you are new here, please mark the answer as solution so others can refere to this. :)

Answer (score 0):

add to submit button few CSS rules:

```
input[type=submit] {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}
```

Comment: Wait... Yours look pretty good already. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: And by the way, do you also know a way to make the gap between the text 'Username' and the TextBox below it a bit bigger? Because it looks so tight, and putting one <br/> next to it make the space to big

Comment: just add to them margin: 10px 0; in your CSS (or any other value you want)

Comment: Would give you a good reputation but I can't do that yet. Thanks anyway!